# Regis connection pooling for Django Application that uses green threads (eventlet)

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, connection-pooling

We have a Django application that uses eventlet as a worker class and is deployed on Heroku. We want to start using Redis (for real-time websocket-based communication) but I don't quite understand how to implement a connection pooling for it.

My understanding is that each green thread that requires communication with Redis  will open a connection. Is it correct?

If yes, what is the strategy for pooling Redis connections in such a scenario, because if each HTTP requests requires a communication with Redis (e.g., for validating session), with no pooling the number of connections will grow very fast.

For PostgreSQL we are using PGBouncer, but I can't find anything similar for Redis.